# Description of function in libv4l2.h and libv4lconvert.h

Tags: webcam, rgb, yuv, v4l2

I am working on webcam and i capture video using v4l2 library but today i found new code for capture video which is using "libv4l2.h" and "libv4lconvert.h". I found that code working in another pixel format which my webcam dose not support. I found some new predefined functions in that code like v4lconvert_create(), v4lconvert_convert() but dose not found any description of there predefined description. so i want description of these function. Please share decsription or any document for these functions.